# sending mail in asp.net core 2.0 to Amazon SES

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ses

I've made a simple form that when it's submitted, I want it to send a mail to my SES Provider in amazon.
How can I achieve this and is there a library in .NET Core 2.0 that allows sending mails?

BTW: I'm using angular in the front end, and for the backend I'm using a WebAPI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this very easily, since AWSSDK fully supports .net Core 2.0.

Install `AWSSDK.SimpleEmail`.

Then:

```
    public async Task<bool> SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string html){
    // might want to provide credentials
    using(var ses = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) 

       {
    var sendResult = await ses.SendEmailAsync(new SendEmailRequest
            {
                  Source = from,
                  Destination = new Destination(to) { CcAddresses = "if you need them", BccAddresses = "or these" },
                  Message = new Message
                     {
                       Subject = new Content(subject),
                       Body = new Body
                       {
                          Html = new Content(html)
                       }
                     }
                 });
         return sendResult.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
       }
}
```